# Page too large for screen when on Firefox. Laptop, Win 7 HP

Tags: firefox, display, webpage

My friend (even less computer-literate than I) just got her first laptop. It was working fine last night, but this morning she may have hit a wrong key. When online, the page extends beyond the edges of her screen. There's a horizontal scrollbar, but it's of limited use. Also, the search and drop-down menu buttons at the top are completely missing. There's basically nothing showing above page tabs.

Can someone help us return her page to the normal size, please? To reiterate, this is *not* happening when she's not online, using regular Windows apps.

Many thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: Try `F11` to toggle the *full screen mode* while in the offending program.  It should work in most.

Answer (score 1):

Press CTRL+0 (that's a zero) to restore the default zoom level.

The other issue may be related to full screen mode. Try pressing F11. Also, I assume you have tried turning it off and on again. If not, do so.

If that does not work, hit the ALT key to get to the menu, and see if you can adjust anything in the "view" menu. (Did you maybe just enter the new "hidden menu bar" mode that is default in current versions of Firefox?)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'll be it's partly the 'hidden menu bar.'  She's also going to reset Firefox; I looked on their site and found out how to do that. Will advise if there are still any problems. If not, thank you very, very much!

Comment: If she hasn't saved passwords, bookmarks etc., just creating a new profile will most certainly fix the problem. I would consider that the nuclear option, though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be anything, and is hard for us to visualize just from a description. However, the problem could be that your zoom level is too high. In that case, you could tune it down by using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> or resetting it by using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>. It could also be that you toggled full screen mode, in which you would turn it off by using <kbd>F11</kbd>. It could also be that she was playing around and removed the menu  bar and the bookmarks bar.